# GCC library linking issue

Tags: gcc, linker, compilation

I am trying to compile Pro*C lib on Linux.I have following code in my make.

```
etc=$TABS_HOME/admin
export etc
if [ -f ${1}.pc ]
then
rm $1_x.o
compc $1
make -f $etc/proc64.mk $1_x.o
ar -cvq  libtabs.a $1_x.o
else
make -f $etc/proc64.mk $1.o
ar -cvq  libtabs.a $1.o
fi
```

Here is the final command that printed when compilation started:

```
/usr/bin/gcc -g  -m64  -g   -I/export/home/cl10gr2/oracle/rdbms/public -I/home/med/src/common -I/u01/app/oradb11r2/product/11.2.0/dbhome_3/rdbms/demo -

I/u01/app/oradb11r2/product/11.2.0/dbhome_3/rdbms/public -
I/u01/app/oradb11r2/product/11.2.0/dbhome_3/precomp/public -ltabs.a -lnapi.a  -c commonutil_x.c
```

I am getting following warning/Error:

```
gcc: -ltabs.a: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: -lnapi.a: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

Can any please help me out why it is not linking the lib files?

Answer (score 3):

Its not linking them because you aren't linking.  You are passing the `-c` option:

> -c  Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link.  The linking stage simply is not done.  The ultimate output is in the form of an object file for each source file.

If you are building intermediate object files, you don't need the libraries until the very end.  Include all of the object files and libraries you need in the final stage and link them all together.

Comment: Thank you Mark for your reply.After building object file, I also doing "ar". so it should generate lib file